# write content in a byte array to a file and read the byte from file back to byte array

Tags: java, arrays

How can write content in a byte array to a file and read the byte from file back to byte array without changing the content  written before. in java

Comment: Just open the file in append mode. use this constructor `FileWriter(String fileName, boolean append)`

Comment: RTFM :: [IO](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/)

Comment: @EddieB if you don't know the answer then pointing someone to the wrong documentation is very unhelpful.

Comment: use `FileOutputStream(File file, boolean append)`

Comment: @Abhishek no. The `File` API is ancient and should be avoided. See my answer.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I know it very well... that's why I sent him to the [IO](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/) tutorials... where I learned it sir... ;)

Answer (score 1):

There are two methods for exactly this, in [`Files`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html)

```
final Path path myFile = Paths.get("path","to","file");
final byte[] toWrite = ...

Files.write(myFile, toWrite, StandardOpenOption.CREATE_NEW);

final byte[] read = Files.readAllBytes(myFile);

assert Arrays.equals(toWrite, read);
```