# Java: I need to get byte array out of outputstream

Tags: java, outputstream, fileoutputstream, bytearrayoutputstream

In my case the out put stream is basically FileOutputStream. Hence for this code:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = (ByteArrayOutputStream) streamToEncrypt;
```

(Where streamToEncrypt is OutputStream) is getting this exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.io.FileOutputStream cannot be cast to java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream
```

**All I need to do is to get the  byte array out of this outputstream.
I do NOT have access to the file at this level. All I have is this output stream that I have to encrypt before pushing it to the file**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [write content in a byte array to a file and read the byte from file back to byte array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29508294/write-content-in-a-byte-array-to-a-file-and-read-the-byte-from-file-back-to-byte)

Comment: To get the contents of a file, you have to read it. If you want to get a byte[] from an OutputStream, use a ByteArrayOutputStream, that is what it for.

Comment: `CipherInputStream` and `CipherOutputStream` may prove helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't get bytes out of an `OutputStream`. You get them out of an `InputStream`. You put bytes into an `OutputStream`.

If bytes have already been written to the `OutputStream`, it's too late. Opening the file again and reading from it is the only way for you to access those data.

If you want to encrypt an output stream, you should construct the stream and pass it to the code that writes to the stream.

```
Cipher enc = Cipher.getInstance("...");
enc.init(...);
try (OutputStream fos = Files.newOutputStream(path);
     OutputStream os = new CipherOutputStream(fos, enc)) {
   writingObject.write(os);
}
```

Comment: enc.init()  needs a public key . I have the key in .asc format. May I get hint on how to create the key using that file/filePath ? I am using "BOUNCY CASTLE" . Thanks for your response

Comment: @Patty Ask separate question for that.

Answer (score 6):

That simply doesn't make any sense.

A ByteArrayOutputStream takes the data you push into it ... and stores them within a **byte array** that you can retrieve later on.

A FileOutputStream takes data ... and pushes it into a **file**.

Those are two completely different classes; you simply can't **cast** one into the other! Thats like you trying to **cast** a String into an Integer; or turning an Apple into a Banana by saying "you apple, now be a banana". Simply wont work!

So, the real "answer" here: you should step back and clarify what exactly you intend to do with your data; and then you use that stream(s) matching that requirement(s).